# Is there a way to return value (date) in dataframe from multiple column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I'm trying to return a date to another column based on the multiple column value as shown in the dataframe below. The expected result is in the column `df['return_date']` where it returned the date before the other column start the value with `'1'`

---

| DATE | column_a | column_b | column_c | column_d | return_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NaN |
| 2/1/2023 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NaN |
| 3/1/2023 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3/1/2023 |
| 4/1/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 5/1/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 6/1/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 7/1/2023 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7/1/2023 |
| 8/1/2023 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 9/1/2023 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9/1/2023 |
| 10/1/2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NaN |

---

I want to learn using the `groupby` for multiple column but I'm not quite familiar with it yet.. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: i expect to create the result as in the last column, `df['return_date']`

Comment: is there always only a single column whose value is `1` for any row?

Comment: yes, each row has only one value of `1` for all four columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your case. You need to detect when a row change with respect to the next, and then in that row you should assign the date.

```py
data = {'DATE': {0: '1/1/2023',
  1: '2/1/2023',
  2: '3/1/2023',
  3: '4/1/2023',
  4: '5/1/2023',
  5: '6/1/2023',
  6: '7/1/2023',
  7: '8/1/2023',
  8: '9/1/2023',
  9: '10/1/2023'},
 'column_a': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 0},
 'column_b': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'column_c': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'column_d': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
row_change = df.filter(like='column').diff(-1).eq(-1).any(axis=1)
df.loc[row_change, 'return_date'] = df.loc[row_change, 'DATE']
```

Comment: its great!, however if its found all `0` column, it will take that date instead of the `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`, in combination with `.cumcount()` to get the required index
And then drag the date from the `DATE` column using that index.

#### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', '3/1/2023', '4/1/2023', '5/1/2023', '6/1/2023', '7/1/2023', '8/1/2023', '9/1/2023', '10/1/2023'],
    'column_a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'column_b': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'column_c': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'column_d': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
})

idx = df[df.groupby(['column_a', 'column_b', 'column_c', 'column_d']).cumcount() == 0].index - 1
df.loc[idx[1:], 'return_date'] = df.loc[idx[1:], 'DATE']

print(df)
```

#### Output

```
        DATE  column_a  column_b  column_c  column_d return_date
0   1/1/2023         0         0         1         0         NaN
1   2/1/2023         0         0         1         0         NaN
2   3/1/2023         0         0         1         0    3/1/2023
3   4/1/2023         0         1         0         0         NaN
4   5/1/2023         0         1         0         0         NaN
5   6/1/2023         0         1         0         0         NaN
6   7/1/2023         0         1         0         0    7/1/2023
7   8/1/2023         1         0         0         0         NaN
8   9/1/2023         1         0         0         0    9/1/2023
9  10/1/2023         0         0         0         1         NaN
```

Comment: hi, thank you for providing a guide, but unfortunately, the date did not passed throughout the column and I couldn’t figure out why.